# How do I change the Apple ID in prompt when Updating xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6.1

When I try the Xcode Update from Appstore in my mac, the password dialogue prompts me with my friend Apple ID; YET, I AM signed in the Apple Store with MY own Apple ID.
I have already verified my ID under Settings/Store. I have also signed out, signing back in with my Apple ID, just in case. No problems there, for I DO sign in with my own ID ok. The problem is just the prompt dialogue for password, when I try to use the 'Update Xcode’ feature it prompts me for password with his ID, not mine.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your version of Xcode was originally downloaded with your friend's Apple ID, and so can only be updated using his credentials (regardless of who is currently logged in). If you want to install it with yours, you'll need to do a new install from scratch while logged in with your account. Go to the download page for Xcode (not the *update* tab), and download it afresh.